# How can I choose function with class fuction?

Tags: python, class, math

```
class ODEsolver():
    def __init__(self):
        self.init=self
  def Euler(self, fcn, x0, y0, xend, h):
    estimate=[y0]
    z=y0
    b=0
    t=x0   
    while(t<xend):
      slope1=fnc(bisection(t,301,1200,10**-4))
      y=z+slope1*h/8
      t+=h
      z=y
      estimate.append(y)
    return estimate

    def Heun(self, fcn, x0, y0, xend, h):
    def RungeKutta(self,fcn,x0,y0,xend,h):

    def solve(self,which, fcn, x0, y0, xend, h):
        if which==0:
            self.Euler(fcn,x0,y0,xend,h)
        elif which==1:
            self.Heun(fcn,x0,y0,xend,h)
        else:
            self.RungeKutta(fcn,x0,y0,xend,h)
```

I'm trying to choose function and get return as `list([])`.
But `e=r.solve(0,diff,0,1200,6000,30)` returns `NONE`.
How can I get right return from this code?

*I simplified other functions such as Heun,RungeKutta because I noticed the problem is in `r.solve()` because simply calling function like `r.Euler` worked well.

Comment: you don't return anything at all from `solve`

Comment: `return self.Euler(fcn,x0,y0,xend,h)`?

Comment: What's the point of choosing in the first place? If you can chose from ``0``, ``1``, ``2``, you can also "chose" from ``self.Euler``, ``self.Heun``, ``self.RungeKutta``. Where is the "``list([])``" supposed to come from?

Comment: Actually the functions `self.Euler`, `self.Heun`, `self.RungeKutta` has return as `estimate=[]` but I cleared out because the problem was I want to use only `self.solve` to call functions.
Sorry to confuse you. I live in Korea so I'm poor at english. I edited the Question now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getattr`.

Like this:

```py
def solve(self, which, fcn, x0, y0, xend, h):
    fn = getattr(self, which)
    return fn(fcn, x0, y0, xend, h)
```

... and then pass the desired method name as the argument:

```py
solver = ODEsolver()
return solver.solve('Euler', 42, 42, 42, 42, 100500)
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning. You just invoked the Euler, Heun and RungeKutta functions. You have to return the answers, try to store the answer in a variable and return it on the end of the function, like this:

```
def solve(self,which, fcn, x0, y0, xend, h):
  if which==0:
    answer = self.Euler(fcn,x0,y0,xend,h)
  elif which==1:
    answer = self.Heun(fcn,x0,y0,xend,h)
  else:
    answer = self.RungeKutta(fcn,x0,y0,xend,h)
  return answer
```